# php регулярные выражения

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть строки:

```
128
129
129а
12А
12Вк1
12а
12к0стр0
```

Нужно получить где только цифры либо цифры и в конце одна буква.

С регулярными значениями не знаком, помогите пожалуйста.

Пробовал писать

```
if (preg_match("/^[(0-9){0,3}+(а-я{0,1})]+$/", $home["name"])).
```

Но это не так работает.

И пробовал `/^\d+|\d+[а-я]?/` тогда все строки пропускает

Answer (score 2):

```
/^\d+[а-яА-Я]?$/
```

- `^` - начало строки
- `\d+` - одна или больше цифр
- `[а-яА-Я]?` - не более одной русской буквы
- `$` - конец строки

https://regex101.com/r/LcSuLt/1

Comment: Спасибо большое! Буду изучать регулярки)

Comment: @Роман Если мой ответ решил Вашу проблему, отметьте его как верный

Answer (score 1):

> *Пробовал писать `if (preg_match("/^[(0-9){0,3}+(а-я{0,1})]+$/", $home["name"]))` Но это не так работает*

Во первых, если вам нужно найти более одного соответствия, то вместо `preg_match()` надо использовать `preg_match_all()` *(глобальный поиск)*

Во вторых, если искомые значения находятся на разных строках, а в качестве ограничителей вы используете `^` и `$`, то нужно в конец шаблона добавлять модификатор `m`

В третьих, внутри квадратных скобок символьного класса `[...]` действуют особые правила, одно из них говорит о том, что почти все метасимволы становятся литералами.

Один из вариантов решения выглядит так:

```
$str = '128 129 129а 12А 12Вк1 12а 12к0стр0';

preg_match_all('~\b\d+\pL?\b~iu', $str, $arr);

var_dump($arr);
```

В результате вы получите набор значений:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => string '128' (length=3)
      1 => string '129' (length=3)
      2 => string '129а' (length=5)
      3 => string '12А' (length=4)
      4 => string '12а' (length=4)
```